# True or False: If $a\perp b$ and $b \perp c$, then $a\perp c$.

Tags: linear-algebra

True or False: Let $a$,$b$,$c \in \mathbb{R^3}$ be linearly independent. If $a\perp b$ and $b \perp c$, then $a\perp c$.

This is false based on my calculus intuition. What would be the linear algebra explanation?

Comment: You could have, for example, $a=(1, 0, 0), b=(0, 0, 1)$ and $c=(1, 1, 0)$.

Comment: @Arthur - a and c should be linearly independent.

Comment: You can also take $c=a$ whatever space you are in.

Comment: @AndreasCap But then $c-a=0$ so they are not linearly independent.

Comment: @skyking Sorry, I overlooked that requirement ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$a = (1, 0, 0)$$
$$b = (0,1, 0)$$
$$c = (1,0,1)$$

we can see that $\langle a, b \rangle = 0, \langle b, c \rangle = 0,\langle a, c \rangle \neq 0,$

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\langle a, b\rangle=\langle b, c\rangle = 0$, therefore you have that $\langle b, \alpha a + \gamma c\rangle = \alpha\langle a,b\rangle + \gamma \langle b, c\rangle = 0$. This means that any linear combination of $a$ and $c$ could make it as $c$, but only a few of them fulfills the last statement $\langle a, \alpha a + \gamma c\rangle = \alpha\langle a, a\rangle + \gamma\langle a, c\rangle=0$.

To phrase it differently, if you have set $a, b, c$ for which all three orthogonalities hold you can find another set $a', b', c'$ for which only the two first hold (just select $c' = a+c$ and the other unchanged). Conversely you can from a triple where only the last orthogonality doesn't hold you can find a new set for which all holds (this is what orthogalization is about).